# How can I copy text with many characters to insert in a note in sap?

Tags: excel, vba, scripting, sap-gui

I have this VBA Code that links cells from an Excel file to SAP (SAP H4 HANA).

```
Sub number_twelve()

Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
Set session = objConn.Children(0)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheet2


session.findById("wnd[0]").maximize
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nfb70"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUKRS").Text = "3800"
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/ctxtBKPF-BUKRS").caretPosition = 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-ACCNT").Text = 
sht.Range("B18").Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO-BLDAT").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/ctxtINVFO- 
BLDAT").caretPosition = 0
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 4
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/txtINVFO-WRBTR").Text = 
sht.Range("I18").Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/chkINVFO-XMWST").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/chkINVFO-XMWST").Selected 
= True
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/cmbINVFO-MWSKZ").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTS/tabpMAIN/ssubPAGE:SAPLFDCB:0510/cmbINVFO-MWSKZ").Key = 
"NS"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM- 
HKONT[1,0]").Text = sht.Range("G18").Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/txtACGL_ITEM- 
WRBTR[4,0]").Text = sht.Range("I18").Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/ctxtACGL_ITEM- 
KOSTL[17,0]").Text = sht.Range("H18").Value
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM- 
EOBJ[35,0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM- 
EOBJ[35,0]").press
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLKEAK:0400/ctxtRKEAK-FIELD[0,24]").Text = 
sht.Range("B18").Value
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub:SAPLKEAK:0400/ctxtRKEAK-FIELD[0,24]").caretPosition = 7
session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM- 
LTEXT[12,0]").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/subITEMS:SAPLFSKB:0100/tblSAPLFSKBTABLE/btnACGL_ITEM- 
 LTEXT[12,0]").press
 session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/subNOTICE:SAPLEENO:1001/btnEENO_TEXTE-EDITOR").press
 End Sub
```

In sap, the transaction defined is for posting debit notes, and so one of the fields to fill in is a text field where you want to say what the debit note is about. It happens that as the text has many characters, I need to write in the "notes".
However, when I save the script, the txt file generates me the following line (following the code shown above):

```
  session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSCMSW_CONTAINER_2102/shellcont/shell").setDocument 1,"e1xydGYxXGFkZWZsYW5nMTAyNVxhbnNpXGFuc2ljcGcxMjUyXHVjMVxhZGVmZjBcZGVmZjBcc3RzaGZkYmNoMFxzdHNoZmxvY2gzN1xzdHNoZmhWRpIFxmcm9tYW5cZmNoYXJzZXQwXGZwcnEye1wqXHBhbm9zZSAwMjAyMDYwMzA1MDQwNTAyMDMwNH1UaW1lcyBOZXcgUm9tYW47fXtcZmhpbWFqb3JcZjMxNTAyXGZiaWRpIFxmc3dpc3NcZmNoYXJzZXQwXGZwcnEye1wqXHBhbm9zZSAwMjBmMDMw"
```

Can anyone help me? What should I change in that last line?
I have in the Excel file a cell with the text (J18)

when I record the script, when I start writing the note, I always get this notification:

[image]

attachment:

[image]

Comment: Maybe the type of GUI element you are talking about is [`GuiOfficeIntegration`](https://help.sap.com/docs/sap_gui_for_windows/b47d018c3b9b45e897faf66a6c0885a8/0484ad043f144233ba259b328c1338de.html). The method `SetDocument` is to replace the whole document (binary/base64). Difficult to generate a MS Office document from scratch. Could you explain what you want to achieve so that to help you find a workaround?

Comment: The goal is to copy the text of cell J18 and paste into the "Word" generated by sap (I added attachment above)

Comment: Could you check in transaction code `FB70` if there's a way to avoid MS Word editor, like a button to switch from Word to simple text editor?

Comment: For long texts there is no other way. For short texts there is a text box and this one works

Comment: If `SetDocument` works correctly, and if you're a robust developer, I guess you could create a `.docx` document from scratch, changing only the text, and compressing all together into a .docx file.